# Sending nested JSON object as parameter in GET request

Tags: python, json, request

I am working on requests module. The URL has a JSON parameter which I would like to make dynamic.

I wanted to make one key's value dynamic in this object, for eg. `value: 030-AABBCC` could be `value : 031-AABBCC`.  How can I do this?

```
{
  "where": {
    "where": {
      "where": {
        "expression": {
          "valueIsRelationField": false,
          "fieldName": "id.stationCode",
          "operator": "eq",
          "value": "030-AABBCC"
        }
      },
      "and": {
        "expression": {
          "valueIsRelationField": false,
          "fieldName": "id.datatypeCode",
          "operator": "eq",
          "value": "HHS"
        }
      }
    },
    "and": {
      "expression": {
        "valueIsRelationField": false,
        "fieldName": "dataValue",
        "operator": "null",
        "value": "false"
      }
    }
  },
  "and": {
    "expression": {
      "valueIsRelationField": false,
      "fieldName": "id.dataTime",
      "operator": "btn",
      "value": "2019-05-01T00:00:00,2021-06-16T17:04:18.928"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just make some value as variable will do?

Comment: As @LeiYang said, use a variable.  `"value": myVariable`

Comment: The JSON value itself is going to be static, for a given request. Do you mean you want to parameter the creation of the request itself? Is the `**` next to `"value": "HHS"` a typo? There's no mention of `030-AABBCC` in the JSON shown.

Comment: @chepner Edited the post to remove typo ** and values. This object will be passed to URL as parameter. I have a list of such station codes [030-AABBCC, 021-BACDEF,..] which I wanted to parametrize.